# Using same State for multiple Menu Items in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, state

I am trying to use the Same State for managing all the Menu Items and the state is not being refreshed properly.

My main page has the following four sections.

```
    <div ui-view="navbar" ng-cloak="" class="codrops-top"></div>
    <div ui-view="leftnavbar"></div>
    <div class="well" ui-view="content">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
```

And i have configured Angular Module to handle the top navbar and the left nav bar using

```
$stateProvider.state('site', {
        'abstract': true,
        views: {
                'navbar@': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/components/navbar/navbar.html',
                        controller: 'NavbarController'
                    }
                ,
                'leftnavbar@'   :{
                        templateUrl:'scripts/components/leftnavbar/leftnavbar.html',
                        controller: 'LeftNavbarController'
                }   
        }
```

And i am trying to refresh the view "content" when a left nav item is clicked.

My Leftnav Controller has the following handler for nav item click.

```
$scope.manageEntity = function(code) {
        // I am passing the code of the item clicked using a Service.
        ElementModel.code = code;
        $scope.toggle();
        $state.go('instance',{reload: true});
    };
```

And here is the code i am using for defining the state 'instance'

```
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('instance',{
        parent: 'site',
        url: '/instance',
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/app/entities/instance/instances.html',
                controller: 'InstanceController'
            }
        }
```

How ever the first time the InstanceController is getting invoked and from then even though i am clicking on other left nav items the view is not getting refreshed. control is reaching $state.go('instance',{reload:true}); how ever it's not entering the InstanceController.

Not sure what i am doing wrong..

Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your handler function $scope.manageEntity" the call to $state.go should probably be like

```
$state.go('instance',{},{reload: true});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working fine now. Some how i missed the second argument in go() method.